# How to find formatter names for field_view_field?

Tags: 7, entities

I have to display field with `field_view_field`
I know I can use formatter name ('text_summary_or_trimmed' as example):

```
print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'body', array(
'type' => 'text_summary_or_trimmed', 
)));
```

But how can I find these all possible formatter names for the field?

Comment: Did you checked this out ?
 https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field_ui!field_ui.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_settings_form/7.x
It may help you?

Comment: Could you elaborate? How can it can help me to know formatter names?